# jquery carrousel plugin not working when i add items dynamically from xml file

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to add items dynamically to a carousel jquery plugin.THe items are added bt the carousel ignores them.

The carousel take the items to show from this:

```
<div class="viewport">
    <ul class="overview">
        <li><img src="images/picture6.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/picture5.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/picture4.jpg" /></li>                  
        <li><img src="images/picture2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/picture1.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm reading a xml file and addings item to the overview UL.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "categories.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
  });

function xmlParser(xml) {
    $(xml).find('categories').eq(0).find('category').each(function () {
        $(".overview").append('<li><img src="images/picture6.jpg" /></li>');
    });
}
```

If i open the source code i can see all the new items inside the UL but the carousel acts like there were only the original ones.

Why is happening this?

The sample i'm working on is : http://demos.koalamedia.es/example/

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-initiate the carousel once new images have been added.

Try changing your ajax function to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "categories.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function() {
        xmlParser();
        $('#slider1').tinycarousel();
    }
});
```